# TCP sqn and ack no

Tags: tcp

Suppose that Host A and B are communicating over a TCP connection, and Host B has
already received from A all bytes up through byte 126. Suppose Host A then
sends two segments to Host B back-to-back. The first and second segments
contain 80 and 40 bytes of data, respectively. In the first segment, the
sequence number is 127, the source port number is 302, and the destination
port number is 80. Host B sends an acknowledgment whenever it receives a
segment from Host A.

1. In the second segment sent from Host A to B, what are the
   sequence number, source port number, and destination port number?
2. If the first segment arrives before the second segment, in the
   acknowledgment of the first arriving segment, what is the
   acknowledgment number, the source port number, and the destination
   port number?
3. If the second segment arrives before the first segment, in the
   acknowledgment of the first arriving segment, what is the
   acknowledgment number?
4. Suppose the two segments sent by A arrive in order at B. The first
   acknowledgment is lost and the second acknowledgment arrives after
   the first timeout interval.How this will be managed ? what will
   happen to acknowledgement and sequence number ?

Comment: no.already got past that :). trying to learn about networking and this questions crossed my mind :)

Comment: Because they read like homework. I mean it should be clear that every segment that goes from A to B carries the same src and dst port numbers.

Comment: well thanks.but question is what about the sequence and acknowledge number ?